# NLog.config file is being updated during VSTS build

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nlog

I'm creating ASP.NET Web API2 in .NET Core 2.0.

I've just created my own NLog.config file. Everything work fine locally, but during VSTS build, the NLog.config file is being updated to default one. 
Just thinking if it can be a overwritten during Nuget Restore? But when restoring packages locally anything happen.

Does anyone meet with something similar? Founded workaround which is changing default config name to e.g NLogProd.config, but want to achieve goal without workaround.

Comment: Have you checked the Nlog.config file after the build process? Not sure why VSTS will update your Nlog.config file, doesn't make sense. Did you get any related error log during build.

Comment: Did you check the build logs to see if there is any entry related to it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by using the NLog.config nuget-package as `<PackageReference>` on .NetCore:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config

Microsoft decided to refactor the nuget-package-format, that caused lots of nuget-packages to [stop working like the NLog.config](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2823) nuget-package.

The solution is to stop using the NLog.config nuget-package, but instead use:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLog-Install